# woocommerce new order alert on a specific non admin page

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I'm relatively new to WordPress but have basic understanding of how it works;
I have a page where non admins can see woocommerce orders, I want to trigger a popup on this page when there is a new order.
What is the easiest way to achieve this. (I tried few plugin but none of them does the job in a simple manner and are bloated). upon some research I feel like woocommerce new order hook and ajax can be used to achieve this, am i correct, is there a better way? any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)